# Not able to fix the prefab in unity 3d which gets its position changed ......

Tags: unity-game-engine

When a destruction animation is played in my script and it completes the prefab returns to initial frame position of the animation , and not in the position previous to the playing of animation.. this object is not destroyed actually and is added to the pool of objects , in order to reappear in the scene, and when it reappears it is in vertical position which is position at the beginning of the animation

Comment: Isn't this just normal behaviour? When the animation ends it starts from the beginning.

Comment: but before completion of animation, prefab respawns ... thats the major problem

Comment: Well, either you need to go more into detail what happens (and when!) or you need to post some code. Otherwise it's just guessing.